# How to use list values as data series of a charts in C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, charts, datasource

There are few List in my program. All list has same no of values(elements)

```
List<Double> list_A= new List<Double>();
```

> { 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 }

```
List<Double> list_B= new List<Double>();
```

> { 100, 300, 200, 500 }

```
List<Double> list_C= new List<Double>();
```

> { 150, 275, 290, 700}

```
List<Double> list_D= new List<Double>();
```

> { 200, 550, 300, 50}

**I need to use the values of these list in a chart as below.**
[image]

As I understand Need to merge List B , List C  and List D with List A and create  new list which are compatible for chart DataSource.

I really appreciate if anyone has a hint about  how to merge 2 list and create a new list which is compatible for chart DataSource

Thanks

Comment: You can use `list_A.Union(list_B)`

Comment: You can also chain the merge using `list_A.Union(list_B).Union(list_C).Union(list_D).ToList();`

Comment: if I use "list_A.Union(list_B).Union(list_C).Union(list_D).ToList();" How can I draw separate lines in a single chart ?

Comment: I'm not sure on drawing part, the suggestion was for question " _anyone has a hint about how to merge 2 list and create a new list_ "

Comment: Probably you can share more code around chart drawing for experts to add their inputs.

Comment: @Sachith do you want to draw the merged lists into the same chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found Solution

```
Series Minimum= chart1.Series.Add("Minimum");
Minimum.Points.DataBindXY(list_A, list_B);
Minimum.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Minimum.Color = Color.Red;
Minimum.BorderWidth = 3;
```